# Symfony2 Forms field of choice or add new entity object

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have quite a problem, I have entities with a `many-to-one` association  defined like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Bundle\Entity\Proxy", inversedBy="meeting", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $proxy;
```

I'd like to create a form with combination like this:

```
array(
      '_blank'  => 'No proxy',
      '_add_new'=> 'Add new',
      'Choose from existing' => array(
                                      '1' => 'John Smith',
                                      '2' => 'Brad Pitt'
      )
)
```

Based on Symfony2 mechanism. So after choose `_add_new` i would add by JavaScript form from prototype for new proxy object or if choose would be an existing one then save id.

It would be a combination of http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html and http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Has anyone idea where to start with this topic?

Comment: did you see this one ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165617/symfony-2-form-with-select-list

Comment: Yes, i'm aware of this, but it`s not a solution for my problem at all

Comment: I figured out that the best solution would be to use dynamic forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html