# Symfony2 FormType entity field type

Tags: php, forms, symfony, orm, entity

I have three entity. `Profile`, `Car` and `Trip`. When user(`Profile`) create `Trip`, he can chose the `Car`(only his own) and assign it to the `Trip`. I know the field must be the entity type. But I dont know how I can set to chose list a cars of current user(Profile). Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165617/symfony-2-form-with-select-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter the cars by user, I think this example is what you need:

```
$builder->add('car', 'entity', array(
    'class'         => '/path/to/entity/Car',
    'property'      => 'title',
    'empty_value'   => 'Choose a car',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $em) use ($userId) {
         return $em->createQueryBuilder('c')
             ->join('c.user', 'u')
             ->where('u.id = :userId')
             ->setParameter('userId', $userId);
         }
    )
)
```

You can add $userId as one form option:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), $object, array( 'userId' => $userId ));
```

And inside your form retrieve it:

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'userId' => function (Options $options, $value) {
            return $options['userId'];
        }
    ));
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if($options['userId']){
        $userId = $options['userId'];
    }
 }
```

Comment: how I can get $userId? when I try get current user by SecurityContextInterface I get error:
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Vputi\TripBundle\Form\Type\TripDriverType::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface, none given,

Comment: I updated my answer above. Also you can inject it in form constructor: new MyFormType($userId);

Comment: thanks a lot man. you answer is that what I need.) take my vote ups)

Answer (score 1):

How I mentioned. other solution, even personally I don't prefer it:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType($userId), $object);
```

And in your form, store it in a protected variable to be used later in your query:

```
/**
 * Class MyFormType
 */
 class MyFormType extends AbstractType
 {

     protected $userId;

     /**
      * @param $userId
      */
     public function __construct($userId) {
         $this->userId = $userId;
     }

 }
```

Comment: and how I can understand even I can declare my form as a service.

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't face with such a scenario until now, but I think that for you case is better not to use the form as service.

Comment: You can add arguments to services, but some from parameters.yml or other services, not ones like user ids.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this Symfony cookbook entry:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#how-to-dynamically-generate-forms-based-on-user-data